# scipy.optimize dll load failure on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, scipy

I am attempting to import scipy.optimize using Python 3.3.1 on Windows 8.  I am using scipy-0.12.0.  When I attempt to import, Python returns the following error:

```
>>> import scipy.optimize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 146, in
<module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 34, in <
module>
    from .linesearch import \
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 16, in
 <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I believe this is an operating system error because importing scipy.optimize succeeds when using the same version of Python and scipy on a Windows 7 machine.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be a problem with using an incompatible version of Numpy.  We solved this problem on a computer at work by **using a Numpy-MKL build** from [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).  This solved our problems on Windows 8 computers, because the builds for Scipy from his website require the Numpy MKL build.

Answer (score 0):

I really encourage you to Install SciPy and NumPy with one these packages:

- [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/)
- [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)
- [Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/)

Other wise you will end up with all the strange error because these packages mainly based on C libraries that they need to be compiled and usually standard Windows installation doesn't have the right compiler.

Comment: +1 I prefer [WinPython](https://code.google.com/p/winpython/) over Python(x,y), because it has 64 bit versions available. But they are basically the same thing, and are both mantained by the same guy.